# ConcurrentHashMap for c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

Is there any ConcurrentHashMap for c++ implementation or something of similar anywhere?

I can't understand why multithreading in c++ is so hard than Java!

Comment: Multi-threading is so hard because before the C++11 standard was released, there was no official memory model that supported it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads arent really supported in C++ so there isnt anything in the standard about thread safe containers. People have obviously made them before.

I think this thing from Intel may help http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/

I have not used it myself yet so no guarentees.

You can also just wrap any container in your own class with a semaphore to make it thread safe.

Good luck.

Comment: both of the tbb hashmaps do not share the same concurrent properties as java's CHM

Comment: This comment is old now :) as threads ( standard cpp ) are supported now in C++ 11 onwards

Answer (score 11):

There is [`tbb::concurrent_hash_map`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506191) and [`tbb::concurrent_unordered_map`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506171) of [Intel TBB](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/)

Comment: @rodi: Well there is a free version of `tbb` library but it is under GPL license.

Comment: there is an implementation in the concrt sample pack at code.msdn.com/concrtextras

Comment: These are not functionally equivalent to CHM

Answer (score 4):

There is a new open-source library called `junction` available that contains several new concurrent maps.

https://github.com/preshing/junction

It’s BSD-licensed, so you can use the source code freely in any project, for any purpose.

Find more detail in [this](http://preshing.com/20160201/new-concurrent-hash-maps-for-cpp/) blogpost.

Thanks to the author [Jeff](https://github.com/preshing).

Comment: I checked it out, the library is pretty cool, however, it seems like it's abandoned/unmaintained

Answer (score 1):

[folly::ConcurrentHashMap](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/main/folly/concurrency/ConcurrentHashMap.h) in folly library. Its interface is very close to std::unordered_map.