# C++ HashMap with multi-threading support

Tags: c++, multithreading, hashmap

I have a need to use a HashMap/ HashTable implementation in C++ and i have the following requirements

1- When new data is being inserted in the hashmap the complete hashmap is not locked, and other threads are allowed to read and also update other keys/ values in the hashmap

2- Multiple keys/ values should be updateable at the same time. i.e. one thread updating key x while the other thread updating key y.

Does such an implementation exist in C++ stl or any other libraries out there? or do i need to write something of my own?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618206/concurrenthashmap-for-c - that question is strikingly similar

Comment: Consider what to do with `y = map[x]; if (!y) map[x] = calculation;`.

Comment: Just to clarify, i am not "just" looking for thread-safety. I don't just want multiple reads, but also multiple writes. Therefore i am not sure if the concurrent map from Intel supports that or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that both the Microsoft PPL implementation of [`concurrent_unordered_map`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504906.aspx#unordered_map) and the [Intel TBB implementation](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_unordered_map_cls.htm) currently have a lock per hash bin.  TBB also has a [`concurrent_hash_map`](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_hash_map_cls.htm) with slightly different semantics.  None of them guarantees any amount of concurrency in their spec.  The only thing the specs guarantee is lack of data races.

If your algorithm is going to be this performance sensitive to the performance of concurrent hash table writes, you are probably in trouble, though.  The cost of acquiring and releasing the locks on every access is similar to the cost of doing the hash-table insert.  So you are going to lose half your performance to locking overhead, and need that much more parallelism to recover it.  Are you sure you can't have a hash-table per thread, and then merge all the hash tables when you are done?  (Some algorithms will let you get away with this, others not.)

**Edit**: I just noticed you are asking to be able to update *keys* concurrently.  This is simply not possible under any concurrent hash table implementation that I'm aware of.  The reason is that this is a read-modify-update operation, which, as @JoopEggen pointed out, just don't work with concurrent container types.  In fact, this is a read-modify-update-modify-update operation.  In order to modify keys you would need to make the whole sequence of operations atomic.  Concurrent container types are monitors: each individual method call can be atomic, but sequences of them are not.