# Simplest concurrent C++11 string keyed map

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, concurrency, unordered-map

Like many C++ devs at some point, I needed a **simple concurrent string-keyed table**, and I wanted it based just on C++11 standard library.

By "concurrent" I mean that multiple threads can work on it without locking each other out (most of the time).

*Update: there are two popular solutions available. Not exactly "simple" but feature rich and performant:*

- [junction](https://github.com/preshing/junction) (BSD license)
- [Intel's TBB](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506171) (Apache license)

Besides, and hoping to save some time to the next working guy/gal around, I am sharing the **simplest** C++11 solution (~40 LOC) I have been able to put together.

The feedback so far has been great in that it helped me finding existing options and improving my simple answer. It would be nice to see other simple answers coming along.

Comment: Concurrent and simple are usually mutually exclusive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ConcurrentHashMap for c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618206/concurrenthashmap-for-c)

Comment: @DanM. this is about *string* maps, not hash maps.

Comment: @gatopeich What is a "string map"? Your question is about string keyed map. Hash amps usually support arbitrary types for keys as long as there is a hash for them (and strings satisfy this).

Comment: I am sorry, but what is your _question_? Sharing a particular (and arguably not the best) implementation is not a question.

Comment: @Kit.my question is about the *simplest* usable implementation, not the *best* of course. I just want to save some time to the next guy around, since I could find nothing as simple _anywhere_. Thanks the constructive feedback below I improved it a little bit. And you are welcome to add another answer!

Comment: And what is wrong with e.g. TBB's [`concurrent_unordered_map`/`concurrent_hash_map`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506171)?

Comment: @rubenvb thanks I did not know that you could use any key type there. Since all the talk about "hashes", I thought the rest was left for the "user" to implement. Why don't you add that as an answer?

Comment: @gatopeich because your question as asked is off topic here in any case. I would suggest instead posting your "solution" to codereview.stackexchange.com for better feedback.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research you end up with one of two options:

1. Wrap you head around some of the super-fast hash table implementations [around](https://www.google.com/search?q=fast%20C%2B%2B%20hash%20table). Import pretty complex/obfuscated 3rd party code, convert your keys to hashes, handle collisions, have fun for quite a while.
2. Compartmentalize your table into smaller locked tables. Use shared pointers to manage the contained data.

Choice #2 solves my current use case with virtually no contention, while not closing doors to future optimization *shall you ever need it*. It actually solves some of the things you will need to "grow" into a more complex solution. Here is how:

```
template <typename Element, unsigned NumBlocks>
class ConcurrentTable
{
    using SharedElement = std::shared_ptr<Element>;

    class InnerMap {
        std::mutex mut_;
        std::unordered_map<std::string,SharedElement> map_;
    public:
        SharedElement get(std::string const& key) {
            std::unique_lock<mutex> lock(mut_);
            auto i = map_.find(key);
            return (i != map_.end()) ? i->second
                : SharedElement{}; // Empty pointer == not found
        }
        bool set(std::string const& key, SharedElement && value) {
            std::unique_lock<mutex> lock(mut_);
            auto [_,created] = map_.insert_or_assign(key, forward<SharedElement>(value));
            return created;
        }
        bool del(std::string const& key) {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(mut_);
            return map_.erase(key);
        }
    };

    std::array<InnerMap, NumBlocks> maps_;
    std::hash<std::string> hash_;

    InnerMap& map_for(std::string const& key) {
        return maps_[hash_(key) % NumBlocks];
    }

public:
    SharedElement get(std::string const& key) {
        return map_for(key).get(key);
    }
    bool set(std::string const& key, SharedElement && value) {
        return map_for(key).set(key, std::forward<SharedElement>(value));
    }
    bool del(std::string const& key) {
        return map_for(key).del(key);
    }
};
```

Now you can instantiate a concurrent table of strings to strings like this:

```
ConcurrentTable<std::string,128> my_concurrent_table;
```

With 128 sub-tables there is plenty of hash-space enough for e.g. 10 concurrent threads to access the table randomly. If you need more threads or less contention, increase the size.

Credit goes to a SO contributor whose words sparked my solution: "if you are doing multi-thread access, you will have to compartmentalize anyway". (Sorry writing form the back of my head, can't find the original quote!)

Comment: Your `get` can create element (that user cannot mutate BTW).

Comment: I believe this implementation is not thread-safe, since `map_for` function has a race condition. It'd be also nice to see some performance benchmarks compared to just simple "std::*map + mutex" and 1 threads vs 2/4 threads. (To be certain that it doesn't perform worse).

Comment: @Jarod42, "my" get can create a default constructed `shared_ptr` thus you can check for nullity there. That works for me and is simple but I will make it throw just to make you happy :-)

Comment: @DanM., I am pretty damn sure `map_for()` does not have a race condition. It is just doing a hash of a constant string value. Unless `std::hash` is essentially broken, that is.

Comment: @gatopeich what if two threads access non-existent (in maps_) element with the same hash at the same time?

Comment: @DanM.: first `maps_` is an `array`, and each component is protected via `mutex`, so it seems good. (`Element` is not protected, but it seems it is out of scope)

Comment: @Jarod42 you are correct. Confused `map_` with `maps_`. SO is not the best suited place to read large chunks of code.
Anyway, if your solution is good enough for you, when it's fine, though I'm not convinced it's a good choice in general case, since it can show suboptimal performance. Also, simple improvement to your design would be to use [shared_mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex)